# restricting invertible maps to get new maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

For $V$ and $W$ as vector spaces, let we define $V\otimes W$ and suppose $T$ be a invertible linear map from $V\otimes W$ to itself with special condition, I want to know whether there exist something like restricted map in order to get a new linear map like $S$ such that $S$ is an invertible linear map on $V$? In addition can we say that $V\otimes\{1\}$ is a subspace of $V\otimes W$?

Comment: What is $\{1\}$ supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

> Let $V,V',W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over $k$ and let $T : V \otimes_k W \to V' \otimes_k W$ be a linear map. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> $\bullet$ $T$ commutes with the $\mathrm{GL}(W)$-action.
>
> $\bullet$ There is some linear map $S : V \to V'$ such that $T = S \otimes \mathrm{id}_W$.

*Proof.* Clearly $S \otimes \mathrm{id}_W$ commutes with the $\mathrm{GL}(W)$-action. Now let us assume that $T$ commutes with the $\mathrm{GL}(W)$-action. By writing $V$ and $V'$ as a finite direct sum of copies of $k$, we may obviously assume that $V=V'=k$, i.e. $T : W \to W$ commutes with the $\mathrm{GL}(W)$-action. Now use my proof at [SE/630842](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630842) to show that $T(w)=\lambda w$ for some $\lambda \in k$. $\square$

Comment: Could you please more explanation on "T commutes with the GL(W)-action" ?

Comment: Well, $V \otimes_k W$ has an obvious $\mathrm{GL}(W)$-action (on the second tensor factor). That means that $T$ commutes with the $\mathrm{GL}(W)$-action iff $T(v \otimes \alpha(w))=(\mathrm{id} \otimes \alpha)(T(v \otimes w))$ for all $v \in V, w \in W$ and $\alpha \in \mathrm{GL}(W)$.

Comment: in addition is ⍺ each an every elements of GL(W)? I mean for all ⍺?

Comment: For all $\alpha$.

Comment: what can we say if T commutes with some of elements of GL(W)?In addition If we consider W=GF(4) as a vector space over GF(2) and let Gal(W/GF(2)) then Can we claim that the above statement is true?

Answer (score 0):

There is no $1$ in $W$, so $V \otimes \{1\}$ doesn't make sense. In a similar vein, there's no canonical way to view $V$ as a subspace of $V \otimes W$, so it would be difficult to restrict any map on $V \otimes W$ to one on $V$ in a natural way.

One could do any number of unnatural things though; after all, (assuming $V, W$ are finite-dimensional) $V \simeq k^n$, $W \simeq k^m$ for some $n, m$, so $V \otimes W \simeq k^{nm}$. Under these isomorphisms, we could "restrict" to $V$ by restricting to the subspace spanned by the first $n$ basis vectors of some basis. Under this basis, a linear transformation $T$ on $V \otimes W$ has the property you're looking for iff the upper left $n \times n$ submatrix of the matrix representing $T$ is invertible. (This is a very ad-hoc construction though. Not something we'd usually do.)